# Many to Many Get All Distinct Values From a Related Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an **Article** model with many-to-many relation with the **Tag** model

The **Article** model

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
}
```

The **Tag** model

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

What I want is to get all the unique tags that have a relation with at least one (or more) article in the articles table. I want to retrieve it through a static method in the **Article** model like below

```
public static function allTags()
{
   // return static:: all the tags
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: this is how I solved it. Appreciate the help!

```
public static function allTags()
{
        return Tag::query()->whereHas('articles', function($query) {
            $query->where('status', '<>', 'draft');
        })->pluck('tag', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `whereHas()`

```
$tags = Tag::query()->whereHas('articles')->get();
```

Comment: I also want to get tags only of the articles that are published, like: 
"where('status', '<>', 'draft')". How can I accomplish this.

Comment: nevermind, I solved it